# Can I replace the contents of a <div> with an external snippet of HTML using JQuery or JavaScript when viewport changes size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head>

    function () {
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        if (viewportWidth < 700) {
            $('#wrapper').load('A.html');
        };

     <body>
         <div id="wrapper">
             <h1>original</h1>
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

I thought that something like this function might do it with A.html being only

```
<h1>small</h1>
```

But I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help offered

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 700) {
        $('#wrapper').load('A.html');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.Have a look at the following code snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var widthCurr=$( window ).width();


        if(widthCurr<=360 && widthCurr>276)
        {

        $('#sample-div').html( "<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>" );
        }
        else if(widthCurr<=276)
        {

        $('#sample-div').html( "<p>I am smaller. <em>You bet!</em></p>" );
        }
        else if(widthCurr>360)
        {
         $('#sample-div').html( "<p>Back to original</p>" );
        }
    });
});
```

In the above example as the width of the window changes,you change the content of the div.    Similarly you can have a condition for height.To get the height you need to use :

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
```

Finally

```
 $(window).resize
```

This is triggered when the size of the window/viewport changes.

Also if the content to be changed is very small,you should use `.html` and not `.load`

Hope this helps